# JSON recursive data ~ PHP CODE

Tags: php, json

Could someone help me think of a smart algorithm?

**Problem**

JSON data looks kinda like this (can't give the real data :/):

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "Start": 1000,
    "End": 1200,
    "Account": {
        "$id": "2",
        "id": "af51f511-e851-4d01-808b-2fa3c070d3ad",
        "aLotMoreInfo": "cool",
        "Parents": {
            "$id": "3",
            "id": "73d7a1f1-82e8-4a7e-bccb-838a251e1a38",
            "aLotMoreInfo": "notcool",
            "Parents": null,
            "Children": {
                "ref": 2
            }
        },
        "Children": null
    }
}
```

Anyways the problem now is that it contains `ref` with a value behind it. The above JSON should be like this:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "Start": 1000,
    "End": 1200,
    "Account": {
        "$id": "2",
        "id": "af51f511-e851-4d01-808b-2fa3c070d3ad",
        "aLotMoreInfo": "cool",
        "Parents": {
            "$id": "3",
            "id": "73d7a1f1-82e8-4a7e-bccb-838a251e1a38",
            "aLotMoreInfo": "notcool",
            "Parents": null,
            "Children": {
                "$id": "2",
                "id": "af51f511-e851-4d01-808b-2fa3c070d3ad",
                "aLotMoreInfo": "cool",
                "Parents": {
                    "$id": "3",
                    "id": "73d7a1f1-82e8-4a7e-bccb-838a251e1a38",
                    "aLotMoreInfo": "notcool",
                    "Parents": null,
                    "Children": null
                },
                "Children": null
            },
            "Children": null
        }
    }
}
```

I need to know two things:

- how to easily get the JSON data which has been stated before
- how do I copy it but set the value `Children` to `null` every single
  time?

I hope someone know a good way how this can be done, because I can't really think of a clever way...

Comment: To easily access data, you previous process - simply store them in `array`by `id` - if you have enough memory for that. You want, simply to change multi level array, to the one in first version? with `ref` as key, not value.